# Query posts by multiple custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I have made two dropdown list which is a custom fields.

**Custom Field 1** :- industry

**Values of Custom Field 1** :- financial_services,ecommerce,insurances, etc.

**Custom Field 2** :- primary_functionality

**Values of Custom Field 2** :-  platform_decision_engine,user_authentication,data_provider_verification etc.

And My **Post Type Name** is :- providers.

Now, I want to fetch posts with multiple custom fields.

So, I have tried this query. But it's not working.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'providers',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'industry',
            'value'     => 'financial_services',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'primary_functionality',
            'value'     => 'platform_decision_engine',
            'compare'   => '='
        )
    )
);
```

Even I tried with for single custom field but it's also not working.

```
// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'providers',
    'meta_key'      => 'industry',
    'meta_value'    => 'financial_services'
);
```

I'm not that much experienced in wordpress. I have read wordpress document but nothing works. I'm confused about **relation** and **compare** in this query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new and confused then please follow these link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068795/wordpress-get-post-based-on-meta-field-content

And

https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html

May be These may help You.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using a WP_Query or  WP_Meta_Query but it shouldn't matter.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'providers',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'industry',
            'value'     => 'financial_services',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array('relation' => 'AND',
            array(
            'key'       => 'primary_functionality',
            'value'     => 'platform_decision_engine',
            'compare'   => '='
) ) ) );
```

See [nested arrays](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/)

Answer (score 0):

`relation` accepts `AND` and `OR` values and tells the query *how* you want to filter the multiple meta queries while `compare` is what determines each meta query is true. So in the attempt you made:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'providers',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'industry',
            'value'     => 'financial_services',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'primary_functionality',
            'value'     => 'platform_decision_engine',
            'compare'   => '='
        )
    )
);
```

You're telling it to look for providers that have `industry` set to `financial_services` *and* their `primary_functionality` is set to `platform_decision_engine`. If it doesn't work, it's either because there is no providers with both of those settings *or* a provider with those settings may have their value saved as not a string but an array of strings, so the `=` is not finding the exact, strict match. I'm guessing it's the latter because you already showed that there's multiple different value possibilities. So maybe try something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'providers',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'industry',
            'value'     => array('financial_services'),
            'compare'   => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'primary_functionality',
            'value'     => array('platform_decision_engine'),
            'compare'   => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```

You can check out the [WordPress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) for more info on the possible values for `compare` here.

Comment: This showed up in my "active" feed and I didn't realize this was asked 4 years ago, whoops!